# Choice of two input files in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, parameters

I'm trying to create a model in ArcGIS Pro that exports selected features in a map, to CAD. It is comprised of two nested models, the first model collects and manipulates the features and the second model (screenshot below) does the actual export to CAD. The export will use one of two "seed" files in the export tool.

How can I setup the model to provide a choice of the two files with one of them set as the default?

[image]

Comment: From a very brief look at Modelbuilder I think this will be hard to do (unless I've missed something obvious). Are you comfortable with Python? You could create a basic tool with Python that achieves this. You then bring that tool into your model.